# Memory Leak in MVC Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, out-of-memory

I have a memory leak in a MVC 3 application I have built. I have used DebugDiag to get some debug information, but am having difficulty understanding the results. The results point to clr!EEHeapAlloc+cb which just keeps going up and up in memory usage, everytime a page is refreshed. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Results follow:

**Function details**

```
Function   clr!EEHeapAlloc+cb 
Allocation type   Heap allocation(s) 
Allocation Count   1507120 allocation(s) 
Allocation Size   1.13 GBytes 
Leak Probability   79%
```

**Call stack sample 1**

```
Address   0x214734a0 
Allocation Time   00:05:02 since tracking started 
Allocation Size   64 Bytes
```

**Function   Source   Destination**

```
clr!EEHeapAlloc+cb      ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap 
clr!EEHeapAllocInProcessHeap+5c      clr!EEHeapAlloc 
clr!operator new+2b      clr!EEHeapAllocInProcessHeap 
clr!CPropertyArray::Set+48      clr!operator new 
clr!CAssemblyName::SetProperty+109      clr!CPropertyArray::Set 
clr!FusionBind::CreateFusionName+2ee       
clr!FusionBind::LoadAssembly+9c      clr!FusionBind::CreateFusionName 
clr!AssemblySpec::FindAssemblyFile+f4       
clr!AppDomain::BindAssemblySpec+2f2      clr!AssemblySpec::FindAssemblyFile 
clr!AssemblySpec::LoadDomainAssembly+2bc       
clr!AssemblySpec::LoadAssembly+19      clr!AssemblySpec::LoadDomainAssembly 
clr!AssemblyNative::Load+297       
System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo, Boolean, Boolean, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark ByRef)      0x1E7B66 
System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(System.String, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)       
System.Environment+ResourceHelper.GetResourceStringCode(System.Object)       
clr!CallDescrWorker+33       
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+8e      clr!CallDescrWorker 
clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+194      clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler 
clr!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+21      clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr 
clr!MethodDescCallSite::Call+1c      clr!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker 
clr!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper+bb       
clr!ReflectionInvocation::ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup+138      clr!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper 
clr!CallDescrWorker+33       
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+8e      clr!CallDescrWorker 
clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+194      clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler 
clr!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+21      clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr 
clr!GetResourceStringFromManaged+198       
clr!GetResourceFromDefault+e2      clr!GetResourceStringFromManaged 
clr!CallDescrWorker+33       
clr!RuntimeTypeHandle::CreateInstance+61e       
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+42e78       
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].UnionWith(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.__Canon>)      0x1EB0BA 
Glimpse.Mvc3.Plumbing.GlimpseDependencyResolver.GetService(System.Type)      0x86A4B2 
System_Core_ni+1cbb28       
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerTypeCache.GetControllerTypes(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1<System.String>)       
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()       
System_Core_ni+1d0f28       
System_Web_Mvc_ni+110c18       
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext, System.String)       
Castle.Proxies.Invocations.DefaultControllerFactory_CreateController.InvokeMethodOnTarget()       
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+65d52       
Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()       
Castle.Proxies.DefaultControllerFactoryProxy.CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext, System.String)      Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() 
System.Collections.Hashtable.InitHash(System.Object, Int32, UInt32 ByRef, UInt32 ByRef)       
System.Web.SiteMapNode.IsAccessibleToUser(System.Web.HttpContext)       
System.Web.StaticSiteMapProvider.GetChildNodes(System.Web.SiteMapNode)       
System.Web.SiteMapNode.get_ChildNodes()       
System.Web.SiteMapNode.get_HasChildNodes()       
MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper.BuildModel(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper, System.Web.SiteMapNode, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Boolean)       
MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper.BuildModel(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper, System.Web.SiteMapNode, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Boolean)      MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper.BuildModel(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper, System.Web.SiteMapNode, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Boolean) 
MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper.Menu(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper, System.String, System.Web.SiteMapNode, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Boolean)      MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper.BuildModel(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper, System.Web.SiteMapNode, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Boolean) 
MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper.Menu(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper, System.Web.SiteMapNode, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Boolean)      MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper.Menu(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper, System.String, System.Web.SiteMapNode, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Boolean) 
MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper.Menu(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)      MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper.Menu(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper, System.Web.SiteMapNode, Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Boolean) 
ASP._Page_Views_Shared__SubMenu_cshtml.Execute()      MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper.Menu(MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MvcSiteMapHtmlHelper, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean) 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()       
0xB373A48       
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext, System.IO.TextWriter, System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase)       
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext, System.IO.TextWriter)       
System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.String, System.Object, System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary)       
ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute()       
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()       
0xB3738BC       
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext, System.IO.TextWriter, System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase)       
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext, System.IO.TextWriter)      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext, System.IO.TextWriter, System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase) 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase+<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(System.IO.TextWriter)      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext, System.IO.TextWriter) 
System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(System.IO.TextWriter)       
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(System.IO.TextWriter, System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)      System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(System.IO.TextWriter) 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(System.IO.TextWriter, System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult) 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(System.String, System.Action`1<System.IO.TextWriter>)       
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(System.String, System.Action`1) 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(System.Web.WebPages.WebPageContext, System.IO.TextWriter, System.Web.WebPages.WebPageRenderingBase)      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() 
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(System.Web.Mvc.ViewContext, System.IO.TextWriter)       
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)       
Castle.Proxies.ControllerActionInvokerProxy.InvokeActionResult_callback(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult) 
Castle.Proxies.Invocations.ControllerActionInvoker_InvokeActionResult.InvokeMethodOnTarget()       
Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()       
Castle.Proxies.ControllerActionInvokerProxy.InvokeActionResult(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)      Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()       
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext, System.Func`1<System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutedContext>)       
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker+<>c__DisplayClass1c+<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b()      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter, System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutingContext, System.Func`1) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1<System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter>, System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult)       
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext, System.String)       
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)       
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)       
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()       
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+<>c__DisplayClass8`1[[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid, System.Web.Mvc]].<BeginSynchronous>b__7(System.IAsyncResult)       
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`1[[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid, System.Web.Mvc]].End()       
System_Web_Mvc_ni+49938       
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(System.Action)       
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(System.Action)       
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult)      System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(System.Action) 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult)       
System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeStepsFromThreadPoolThread(System.Exception)       
System.Web.HttpApplication+AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(System.IAsyncResult)      System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeStepsFromThreadPoolThread(System.Exception) 
System.Web.HttpAsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Object, System.Exception, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus)       
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.PollLockedSessionCallback(System.Object)      System.Web.HttpAsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Object, System.Exception, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus) 
0x8CFA453       
System.Threading._TimerCallback.TimerCallback_Context(System.Object)       
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)       
clr!CallDescrWorker+33       
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+8e      clr!CallDescrWorker 
clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+194      clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler 
clr!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+21      clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr 
clr!MethodDescCallSite::Call+1c      clr!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker 
clr!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper+bb       
clr!ReflectionInvocation::ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup+138      clr!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper 
clr!CallDescrWorker+33       
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+8e      clr!CallDescrWorker 
clr!DispatchCallBody+20      clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler 
clr!DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper+75      clr!DispatchCallBody 
clr!DispatchCallNoEH+53      clr!DispatchCallDebuggerWrapper 
clr!AddTimerCallback_Worker+70      clr!DispatchCallNoEH 
clr!Thread::DoExtraWorkForFinalizer+114       
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+36051       
clr!DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame::`vftable'       
clr!_except_handler4       
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+366e2       
clr!Thread::RaiseCrossContextException+3e1       
0x1089228       
clr!`string'+3c       
clr!`string'+3c       
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+36051       
clr!DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame::`vftable'       
clr!_except_handler4       
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+29219       
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::AsyncTimerCallbackCompletion+83       
clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+195       
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart       
clr!SlowClrFlsSetValue+42       
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+41b4f       
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart       
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart       
clr!operator delete+41       
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart       
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+41bd8       
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+4b       
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e       
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+70       
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b      ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart 
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc
```

Comment: So, this would mean the CLR is leaking memory? Although not impossible, it would be rare...

Comment: Do you notice that is an array creation there ?

Comment: not sure, but the site does use mvcsitemap and when i remove this the memory leak is a lot less, but the clr still increases albeit very slowly, so not sure if the mvcsitemap is causing the leak or its something else, and having mvcsitemap in the site just adds to the memory leak. Other plugins used: structuremap, webactivator and  entity framework 4.3

Comment: I have noticed more outofmemoryexception errors in development since adding the sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

Does you application use COM/Interops?  If so then the CLR could be causing the leak through these unmanaged objects.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the MVC code it's hard to tell exactly what is causing the problem.  .NET's heap allocation is different than the standard heap in C. Since memory is managed based on the number of references an object has, the .NET framework in most cases handles managing this memory.  One thing to keep in mind though is that you don't have an unlimited amount of memory, that's a big misconception with the managed runtime.

Essentially what is happening here is that your application is trying to allocate memory for an object on the managed heap.  The heap is given a certain allocation of memory, and when there is no more memory in that allocation garbage collection will occur.  During garbage collection the managed runtime will build a graph of the items that are still referenced.  Items that are still "alive" and in use.  The garbage collector will then go through and move items that are still in use near each other.  It also will assign a generation on each pass, the reason behind this is that .NET assumes that things that have been alive longer will stay alive.  .NET will then deallocate items on the heap that are not referenced any longer.  If after this there is still no room left to allocate the memory you're trying to allocate the OutOfMemoryException is thrown.

Now most likely what's happening in your application is that you're not deallocating memory properly.  There are a few places to look.  First look to see if you're loading large amounts of data into strings, second look to see if you're overusing static data structures that are growing over time.  Static datastructures are created once per process, therefore if you are constantly inserting items to them and not reducing their size they can quickly create an OutOfMemoryExceptoin. Look to see if you're using unmanaged or unsafe code anywhere in your application, this will include referencing COM interops these can leak memory for sure, and if you do use them you should use the Marshall.Release in an IDisposable pattern  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.release(v=vs.110).aspx this will ensure that the .NET framework releases the COM when garbage collection occurs.  Finally look to see if you can implement the IDisposable and using the "using" statement son objects that do implement the IDisposable pattern to dispose of them properly.